# How to set multiple relayhost in postfix?

Tags: postfix

I want to have a list of hosts in `relayhost`, and when postfix tries to send an email, it sends it to any of them, and if that one is offline, it tries another one.

Can it be done in the config-file, or do I need to play with DNS-settings?
if I give `relayhost` a made-up `hostname` that have multiple mx records, will it try all?
If I give `relayhost` a made-up `[hostname]` that have multiple a records, how will it handle it?

ref: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost

Answer (score 13):

> Multiple destinations are supported in Postfix 3.5 and later.

```
relayhost = mail1.example.com:587, mail2.example.com:587
relayhost = [mail1.example.com]:587, [mail2.example.com]:587
```

Comment: nice, 3.5 was released 2020-03-16, about 4 years after the original question was ask :-)

Comment: It's worth noting that this will always use the first server unless it's not available, so it's not useful for load balancing. This is unlike if you use round-robin DNS, which is useful for load-balancing.

Answer (score 8):

Postfix doesn't allow defining multiple entries for `relayhosts` for redundancy. Have a look at the page you have referenced:

> In the case of SMTP, specify **a** domain name, hostname, hostname:port,
>   [hostname]:port, [hostaddress] or [hostaddress]:port. The form
>   [hostname] turns off MX lookups.

As you can see, there is no way to define multiple addresses/hostnames here.

> if I give relayhost a made-up hostname that have multiple mx records,
>   will it try all?

I guess so, but if it requires authentication, then it may not work with the secondary server anyway and fail.

> If I give relayhost a made-up [hostname] that have multiple a records,
>   how will it handle it?

It will use the first address (A record) returned by the dns in round robin method. But this also doesn't imply that it will try another one in case the one returned by the dns server fails.

Having said that, you may have a look at this postfix option: [smtp_fallback_relay](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_fallback_relay)

Comment: The smtp_fallback_relay was a great help! I have redundant WAN links and often DNS has issues when the link fails over so using this tip I was able to make email delivery more robust with these tweaks: 

/etc/postfix/main.cf
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_fallback_relay = [74.125.28.108]:587

/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 user@gmail.com:password​
​[74.125.28.108]:587 user@gmail.com:password​

Comment: Looks like `smtp_fallback_relay` doesn't work for permanent bounces, which is exactly what I was looking for. Some 3rd party mail server bounces and I would like to forward those to my own mail server. But that additional forwarding of bounces to `smtp_fallback_relay` doesn't seem to happen. The docs for `fallback_relay` say the following: `Optional list of relay hosts for SMTP destinations that can't be found or that are unreachable.` That would easily explain why it doesn't work, the primary relay server IS reachable.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to go with **DNS**.

But you don't need to set multiple MX records - you need to resolve the given hostname with multiple A-Records (host should resolve to a given set ip addresses).

Having multiple hosts to handle traffic is quite common for mail. This is done using multiple mx records. So it's just straight forward when you'll use the same setup when sending from your own host/relay.